# Small space when opening achievements and inbox

Tags: bug, mobile-web, achievements-dialog, mobile-safari, ios

If you open the achievements dialog or the inbox messages there is a small gap at the right side of the screen. You can see it between the gray border and the end of the browser window.

> [image: Screen shot]

This is visible when using iOS 9.0.1.

Comment: Hey Patrick no freehand red circle? Will make it easy to spot.

Comment: Agreed. I use free online Pixlr.com to edit the photos. But that's extra work.

Comment: Does it work on mobile?

Comment: Never tried. Give it a shot... BTW, there is a also extra 'Gray' line on the top  i.e. right corner of achievements bars.

Comment: I think that is the border of the `Achievements`.

Comment: Could be but it looks orphaned now... Something is wrong in the UI, for sure.